# Redirect an image's http get request in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http

`Context
React app runs on localhost:3000
Express API listens on localhost:3300
I use React-Router`

I have this project where I need to inject documentation content inside a react app. Because this documentation is in `.md` and comes from an external gitlab repo, I need to `fs.readdir` to list all the files available and `fs.readFile` to get their content.

For that I've set some endpoints on my Express API and I've `git submodule`d the documentation's repo into my api's directory

The problem is, in that documentation are some images that I need to fetch dynamically too.

Right now, the images' `src` urls from the documentation, once rendered into my react app, try to get the images from said react app and not from the API.

I've tried :

1. Creating a `<Route>` in my React Router that would create a picture component `PictureComp.js` that'd fetch the picture from the API and render it but it doesn't work
2. `import img from './PictureComp';` but it doesn't work because it renders the md from the server in a variable in the `return` of the `render` function, so it's too far down the rabbithome to be replaced.

Is there a way I could intercept the `http GET` request that's launched and redirect it to my API, using React-Router, VanillaJS or other tools?